# Going to a url using C#

Tags: c#, php, email, unity-game-engine

Here is my php script which just sends an email...

```
<?php
    $headers = "From: info@mycompany.com" . "\r\n";
    mail("info@mycompany.co.nz", $_GET["subject"], $_GET["body"], $headers);
?>
```

I go to this url in my chrome browser...

`http://www.myserver.com/myPHPScript.php?subject=Test Email&body=This is a test email`

...and it successfully executes the php script and sends the email.

Now the problem - I try to replicate this in C# by doing the following...

```
// Start this method by calling StartCoroutine (SendMail());
public IEnumerator SendMail() {
    string body = "This is a test email";
    string subject = "Test Email";
    WWW www = new WWW("http://www.myserver.com/myPHPScript.php?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
    yield return www;
}
```

However, it does not work. How can I get this C# script to perfectly emulate going to the url like in my chrome browser.

Comment: What is the `WWW` class?  I'm not familiar with it.  It's not part of .NET that I am aware of.

Comment: It is here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: @Ogen: To send email using C#, you need to have details such as SMTP, emailid, password etc. But to just go to another Url using Response.Redirect(url).

Comment: @Anurag But I don't understand, what is chrome doing that my c# isnt doing? Isn't the chrome simply sending a request to the php script? Which is what my c# is doing

Comment: @Ogen: What is WWW class? Does the above code compile? I don't have much info on PHP to be very honest. Do you want your C# code to execute your PHP script? or Do you want to simply send an email using C#?

Comment: you dont seem to be using proper escaping on the URL per the documentation's requirements. @anurag hes trying to use this as a way to send emails from a game hes developing in unity.

Comment: Does it really have spaces in the subject and body? that doesn't look like a valid url to me (Does chrome treat them as %20s?)

Comment: Yes in chrome when you type a space, you can see that it turns them into %20

Comment: Does that solve your problem then? `subject.Replace(" ", "%20")`?

Comment: no it does not, WWW.EscapeURL doesnt either

Answer (score 2):

Most likely case is that your subject and/or body isn't URL friendly. Unity's WWW class provides a way to do so.
[WWW.EscapeURL method](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html)

so just change this one line in your code
`WWW www = new WWW(WWW.EscapeURL("http://www.myserver.com/myPHPScript.php?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body));`

and it should work.

Comment: Can you post what the result of the WWW.EscapeURL is, as well as what the link looks like in Chrome (verbatim).

Comment: EscapeURL with the url with no arguments is `http%3a%2f%2fwww.myserver.com%2fmyPHPScript.php`. I am supplying the arguments via WWWForm.AddField()

Answer (score 1):

I had to encode the subject and body to escape characters. (EG, " " gets replaced with %20)

I used this link: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm?state=none&origval=www.google.com%2Fffds.php%3Fname%3Do%3Agen&enc=on

Then on the php side of things - I used `rawurldecode(string)` which converts the hex-escaped characters back into their literals